# monitoring zookeeper on znode child add and delete

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am looking for a Zookeeper Recipe to monitor operations performed in a parent node (add child, delete child, etc)

I am unable to figure out how to use the watcher to get the events. Any help is appreciated.

```
import org.apache.zookeeper.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ZookeeperMonitor {
    private static ZooKeeper zookeeper;

    public ZooKeeper connect(String connectionString, int port) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ZookeeperWatcher watcher = new ZookeeperWatcher();
        zookeeper = new ZooKeeper(connectionString, port, watcher);

        return zookeeper;
    }

    public void checkForChanges() throws KeeperException, InterruptedException {
        zookeeper.getChildren("/parent",new ChildChangeWatcher());
    }
}


class ZookeeperWatcher implements Watcher {

    public void process(WatchedEvent watchedEvent) {
    }
}

class ChildChangeWatcher implements  Watcher {
    public void process(WatchedEvent e) {
        if(e.getType() == Event.EventType.NodeChildrenChanged){
            System.out.println("change in children");
        }
    }
}
```

how do I run this as a long-running daemon?

Also is `watcher` alone enough or should I use a `callback`. I did not understand the purpose of callback here.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need children watcher, make the parentNode implement watcher

`public void checkForChanges() throws KeeperException, InterruptedException { zookeeper.getChildren("/parent",this); }`